# Where does ScriptResource.axd gets its Javascript files from?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, scriptmanager

My ScriptResources.axd calls load the wrong (old) javascript versions. Looks like it gets something from the AjaxControlToolkit instead of the newer MS versions.
Where can I change this? Or how can I figure out what is happening?

Based on the answer below, I checked my configuration:

```
<add verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" validate="False"/>
```

Which looks good to me. But still, ScriptResources.axd returns:

```
// (c) 2010 CodePlex Foundation
(function(n,t){function w(){function
```

Also, if I switch to `EnableCdn="True"` in the ScriptManager it works for the WebResource.axd, which then takes the files from CDN, but the ScriptResources.axd is not replaced and still using the old codeplex files.

As a sidenote: This all works on my coworkers PC, but couldn't' find the difference yet.

Answer (score 0):

The resources used to generate the content output (JS) are compiled within the application (this is a the "build action : Embedded Resource" in files properties). If the content loaded is the AjaxControlToolkit, then you should have a look at your **ScriptManager** configuration (it is probably the AjaxControlToolkit's script manager).

Additionnal note: the handler is usually defined by the following section in the Web.config file (although Telerik might use a custom handler for their files such as themes / javascript):

```
<httpHandlers>
  <add verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" 
    type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, 
    System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, 
    PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" validate="false" />
</httpHandlers>
```

Comment: If deinstalled the AjaxControlToolkit a while ago, so it should use the normal ScriptManger. I've checked the web.config in the .Net Framework installation and it looks correct: <add verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" validate="False"/>